# Xcode error: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 using Cometchat cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, cometchat

I'm using Cometchat Ionic sdk, I've added the cordova plugin with `ionic cordova plugin add cometchat_sdk_folder` and it works in android but when I compile for iOS I'm getting this error:

[Output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lV2y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved and a new version of our SDK has been released. If you still face this issue, feel free to email us.

Thanks,

Comment: i can't be able to build ios and generate ipa file after addition of cometchat sdk. How can i solve this error, please some advice, I have already spent 3 or 4 days to solve this issue, but no any luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're unable to replicate the issue. Can you please try using our latest SDK and let us know if the error still persists?

Answer (score 0):

Both the cometchat-ui and MessageSDKFramework frameworks contain an implementation of the Reachability module, which both define the same symbols.

AFAIK, to solve this you need to get/create a version of either framework without the Reachability module.

To do this, you need to have the source code of either framework. You need to change the build process/script so that it does not include the Reachability module. Then you need to rebuild either framework and include include that in your app's Xcode project.

If you don't have the source code of either framework: I think there should be linker options to ignore either duplicate module, or ignore there errors. I leave this to you.

Comment: See extended answer.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try

Comment: Can't find any linker options to do it.